# Not able to parse json without model

Tags: ios, json, swift

I'm making an api call and getting the response like so..

```
    if let data = NSData(contentsOf: NSURL(string: "http://test.chatongo.in/testdata.json")! as URL) {

        do {
            if let response = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data as Data, options: []) as? NSDictionary {
                print("THE RESPONSE IS: \(response)")
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

And the response I get like so...

```
THE RESPONSE IS: {
    Message = Success;
    Status = 200;
    data =     {
        Records =         (
                        {
                Id = 1;
                collectedValue = 500;
                endDate = "10/06/2018";
                mainImageURL = "http://iphonedeveloperguide.com/oneinr/project1.jpg";
                shortDescription = "This foundation will bring smile on there faces";
                startDate = "05/05/2018";
                title = "Smile Crowdfunding";
                totalValue = 5000;
            },
          {
                Id = 2;
                collectedValue = 750;
                endDate = "08/06/2018";
                mainImageURL = "http://iphonedeveloperguide.com/oneinr/project10.jpg";
                shortDescription = "This foundation will help animals";
                startDate = "05/05/2018";
                title = "Animal Funding";
                totalValue = 20000;
            }
        );
        TotalRecords = 10;
    };
}
```

But how do I parse this json and get the individual elements out of it including the image, that I'm not able to figure out.

Comment: Use [String: Any] in your cast instead of NSDictionary since it's much better to use Swift types.

Comment: Also, drop `NSURL` usage, use `URL` directly(then you won't need to cast it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var records = [Record]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: "http://test.chatongo.in/testdata.json")!) { (data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            do {
                let res = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)    
                self.records = res.data.records
                 print(res.data.records)
                 // if it's a collection/table wrap the reload here inside DispatchQueue.main.async
            }
            catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}



// MARK: - Empty
struct Root: Codable {
    let status: Int
    let message: String
    let data: DataClass

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case status = "Status"
        case message = "Message"
        case data
    }
}

// MARK: - DataClass
struct DataClass: Codable {
    let totalRecords: Int
    let records: [Record]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case totalRecords = "TotalRecords"
        case records = "Records"
    }
}

// MARK: - Record
struct Record: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let title, shortDescription: String
    let collectedValue, totalValue: Int
    let startDate, endDate: String
    let mainImageURL: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "Id"
        case title, shortDescription, collectedValue, totalValue, startDate, endDate, mainImageURL
    }
}
```

---

Tip : Don't use `NS` stuff in swift and avoid using `Data(contentsOf:` as it blocks the main thread

Comment: Thanks @Sh_Khan..but how do I show individual elements from `res` into an array of `Root`

Comment: you need to access `records` ??

Comment: Ok @Sh_khan..so if I want to display the title in a tableview then should I do it like this in the `cellForRowAt...    for element in recordsArray {
            cell.titleLabel.text = element.title
        } `

Comment: no do `cell.titleLabel.text=recordsArray[indexPath.row].title`

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways, one way to create a modelobject of

```
struct RecordItem : Codable {
var id : Int?
var collectedValue : Int?
var endDate : String?
var mainImageURL: String?
var shortDescription : String?
var title :String?
var startDate : String?
var totalValue : Int?
}
and 
struct Records : Codable {
var items : [RecordItem]?
}
```

and use this. = let item = data [index] 
print (item. collectedValue) and so on.

seconds methods, you already created dict, then extract all keys and array objects using ["Key": "Value"] and set to any variable.